# No OutputCache for UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, outputcache

I have a page with a list of lot of Products from the database. And on that same page I have some info of the logged in user. This info is in a UserControl. 
(It is not possible to put the list with products in a UserControl :))

So I set this at the top of my page to cache the page

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="200"
   Location="Any"
   VaryByParam="none"
%>
```

But because this caches the whole page, the UserControl with the user info is also cached.
Is it possible to disable the caching for only the UserControl, but not for the rest of the page?

I had a look at Substitution Blocks. But it seems that this only works with text?

Thanks,

Vincent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227429.aspx):

> To allow you to cache a page but substitute some content dynamically,
>   you can use ASP.NET post-cache substitution. With post-cache
>   substitution, the entire page is output cached with specific parts
>   marked as exempt from caching. In the example of the ad banners, the
>   AdRotator control allows you to take advantage of post-cache
>   substitution so that ads dynamically created for each user and for
>   each page refresh.
>
> There are three ways to implement post-cache substitution:
>
> - Declaratively, using the Substitution control.
> - Programmatically, using the Substitution control API.
> - Implicitly, using the AdRotator control.

I think the best option would be using of `Substitution` control. For this add a `Substitution` control to your page, and set its `MethodName` property:

```
<asp:Substitution runat="server" MethodName="GetUserInfo"></asp:substitution>
```

Now add `GetUserInfo` method to your page. The `Substitution` control calls this method to retrieve the user info:

```
public static string GetUserInfo(HttpContext context)
{
    // return rendered user control
}
```

The thing left is to render your user control into  a string. For this you could use a technique proposed in the [Tip/Trick: Cool UI Templating Technique to use with ASP.NET AJAX for non-UpdatePanel scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx) article by Scott Guthrie. In this case to render the user control just use something like:

```
return ViewManager.RenderView("UserInfo.ascx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the product list in a `Session`. Now access it anywhere from the application.

```
YourColectionClass variable = Session["Sessionvariable"] == null ? 
            ClassObject.DatabaseFunction(Params) : 
            (YourColectionClass)Session["Sessionvariable"];
```

---

Now `Cache` it on the basis of `VaryByparam`. `VaryByParam` can have UserID.